# Проблема с векторными изображениями, Android

Tags: android, vector, vector-drawable

У меня возникла проблема: Android не полностью поддерживает векторные изображения, созданные в Inkscape. Например, когда я создаю какой-либо размытый объект, Android его воспринимает как чёткий. Можно ли как-то, кроме экспорта изображения в png и распределения его по плотности экрана, решить эту проблему? Спасибо.

Comment: Применять эффект в рантайме самописным кодом. Либо поискать библиотеку, чтобы использовать svg-файлы в оригинале.